# How to insert comment in iceberg table?

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I'm trying to put a comment on the ICEBRG table in glue catalog, and I used it as follows:

```
spark.sql(f"""CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {schema_name}.{table_name}({columns})
USING iceberg
COMMENT 'table description'
PARTITIONED BY ({partition_by_create})
LOCATION '{bucket_name}'""")
```

I also tried like this
`OPTIONS('comment' = '{comment_table}')`

In both ways it creates the table inserts the comments in the fields but does not insert the comment in the table

In the glue catalog it appears as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know how to insert this comment correctly?

Comment: use `TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = 'foo bar')`

Comment: @shay__, I've already used it, it seems that no property passed via spark appears in the glue catalog, they create it in the json of the iceberg data but do not display it in the glue